# What is the inverse of torch.fft.fft() for pytorch1.10?

Tags: pytorch, fft

I am using `1.10.2+cu113`.
In pytorch 1.7, the code is

```
ffted = torch.rfft(input, 1, onesided=False)
iffted = torch.irfft(ffted, 1, onesided=False)
```

I want to migrate it in new version of pytorch.
Here is my code.

```
ffted = torch.fft.fft(input)
iffted = torch.fft.ifft(ffted)
```

But `iffted` is complex. That is not what I want. I did not found the inverse function of `torch.fft.fft`.

So what is the correct function I should call?
BTW: `input.shape=torch.Size([1, 1, 4000, 10])`

Comment: `torch.fft.ifft` is the inverse of `torch.fft.fft`, but because the implementation doesn't know that your input is real, it has to cover for the general case where the result would be complex. In your example with a real valued input, the imaginary part should consist of negligible residual round-off errors that can be safely ignored. That said, if you know the time domain is real-valued, you should probably be using `torch.fft.rfft`/`torch.fft.irfft` (as far as I know it's still available in pytorch 1.10).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It works. But `torch.fft.rfft` returns one-sided representation. That is not what i want.